# Does Anyone Know Of A Solid Web Example Using ASP.NET MVC1 or MVC2, NHibernate, Fluent NHibernate & Castle?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent

I am looking for solid non-console examples of how to use ASP.NET MVC1 or MVC2, NHibernate, Fluent NHibernate & Castle. I looked at Sharp Architecture and its just too much to digest for my newbie mind. I need a clean, clear, concise Step A, Step B, Step C tutorial or a solid example that is a web application and not a console application. I have searched and searched and searched and I have found incomplete examples (examples with just enough information to make me say where does that code go), console applications and no good web application examples. Does anyone know of a COMPLETE web example? If I see another console example, I'm going to scream....

Comment: What is the difference between a console and a web project in an NHibernate context?

Comment: I need something that shows me the best practices for the setup. The console apps that I have seen show various ways to set up sessionfactories that don't make sense to me when applied to the concept of a stateless web application. Console apps have no global.asax. Their setup is also very simple in relation to most web applications. I need a web example to give me a starting point - a starting point that is a web application. Do you know of any?

Comment: Castle has multiple subprojects.  In this case, I assume you are referring to Windsor.

Comment: You are right Michael. I do mean Windsor.

Comment: `What is the difference between a console and a web project in an NHibernate context?` @Paco About as much as the difference between night and day. NHibernate is all about session management patterns, and the patterns for web app vs thick app are about as different as night and day.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

http://tekpub.com/view/aspmvc/1

AND

http://tekpub.com/view/mvc3/1

I cannot recommend these videos enough and they have an incredible MVC sample project to go along with them here.

https://github.com/tekpub

- Max

Comment: Thank you Max. I'm going to review this site and its documentation/code.

Comment: @Max the link you mentioned is not working, it was showing error 404 .... I  am searching for the sample on how to integrate and how to use nhibernate with asp.net web application... would you pls suggest any links that will shows how to use nhibernate with asp.net web application.....

Comment: hey @pratapchandra, it looks like they changed their site around and the URLs broke. I fixed them and also the github link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Search for Nerd Dinner variants. This sample project is complex enough to be considered real world but also limited enough to not lose scope of teaching technology as opposed to being an exercise in completing business logic.

There are enough variants out there that you should find one with the assortment of tools you're looking for.